# Cartesian plane line Series with Axis Values in the middle of crossing section

Tags: livecharts

I have a wpf application and I am using LiveChart2 for Cartesian LineSeries , But I am not able to set the X & Y axis values at the Center of the two Coordinates with Arrow. Please find my below screenshot, that way I need, please help me.

[My Requirement is like this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vBJRc.png)

There is the ZeroPaint property on the axis, it enables us to set a Paint for the 0 value separator. I followed this link , though it crosses the 2 axis , but i want along with the crossing all points should be displayed in the middle , that is in crossing section, like a Cartesian Plane.

https://livecharts.dev/docs/WPF/2.0.0-beta.950/samples.axes.style